# How to send MarkDown to API

Tags: json, rest, markdown

I'm trying to send Some Markdown text to a rest api. Just now I figure it out that break lines are not accepted in json.

Example. How to send this to my api:

```
An h1 header
============

Paragraphs are separated by a blank line.

2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`. Itemized lists
look like:

  * this one
  * that one
  * the other one

Note that --- not considering the asterisk --- the actual text
content starts at 4-columns in.

> Block quotes are
> written like so.
>
> They can span multiple paragraphs,
> if you like.

Use 3 dashes for an em-dash. Use 2 dashes for ranges (ex., "it's all
in chapters 12--14"). Three dots ... will be converted to an ellipsis.
Unicode is supported. ☺
```

as

```
{
    "body" : " (the markdown) ",
}
```

Comment: You need to "escape" your Markdown text before adding it to your JSON object.. As you didn't tell us which language/framework you are using, here's some general search results for "[escape json](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=escape+json)".

Comment: Put your Markdown in a string or string-like object. Put that string into an appropriate data structure. Use your language's data-to-JSON function. (Hint: **_Never_** build JSON manually.)

Comment: Thanks guys, It was a general question, but i got it. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're trying to send it to a REST API endpoint, I'll assume you're searching for ways to do it using Javascript (since you didn't specify what tech you were using).

Rule of thumb: except if your goal is to re-build a JSON builder, use the ones already existing.

And, guess what, Javascript implements its JSON tools ! ([see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON))

As it's shown in [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), you can use the JSON.stringify function to simply convert an object, like a string to a json-compliant encoded string, that can later be decoded on the server side.

This example illustrates how to do so:

```
var arr = {
    text: "This is some text"
};
var json_string = JSON.stringify(arr);
// Result is:
// "{"text":"This is some text"}"
// Now the json_string contains a json-compliant encoded string.
```

You also can decode JSON client-side with javascript using the other `JSON.parse()` method ([see documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)):

```
var json_string = '{"text":"This is some text"}';
var arr = JSON.parse(json_string);
// Now the arr contains an array containing the value
// "This is some text" accessible with the key "text"
```

If that doesn't answer your question, please edit it to make it more precise, especially on what tech you're using. I'll edit this answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the line-endings with `\n` and then pass it in your `body` key.

Also, make sure you escape double-quotes (**`"`**) by `\"` else your body will end there.

```
# An h1 header\n============\n\nParagraphs are separated by a blank line.\n\n2nd paragraph. *Italic*, **bold**, and `monospace`. Itemized lists\nlook like:\n\n  * this one\n  * that one\n  * the other one\n\nNote that --- not considering the asterisk --- the actual text\ncontent starts at 4-columns in.\n\n> Block quotes are\n> written like so.\n>\n> They can span multiple paragraphs,\n> if you like.\n\nUse 3 dashes for an em-dash. Use 2 dashes for ranges (ex., \"it's all\nin chapters 12--14\"). Three dots ... will be converted to an ellipsis.\nUnicode is supported.
```